# Canonical Request to AWS Signature 4 is correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, signature, aws-secrets-manager, aws-signature

I'd like to ask if there's any error in my canonical request, im trying to create one to the AWS Secrets Manager taking the sample request by example.

Doc:[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Sample Request:
`POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: secretsmanager.region.domain
Accept-Encoding: identity
X-Amz-Target: secretsmanager.GetSecretValue
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
User-Agent: 
X-Amz-Date: 
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=,SignedHeaders=, Signature=
Content-Length:

{
"SecretId": "MyTestDatabaseSecret",
}`

My Canonical Request:
`POST
/GetSecretValue

accept-encoding:identity
content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:secretsmanager.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:beaead3198f7da1e70d03ab969765e0821b24fc913697e929e726aeaebf0eba3
x-amz-date:20230111T145646Z
x-amz-target:secretsmanager.getsecretvalue

accept-encoding;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
beaead3198f7da1e70d03ab969765e0821b24fc913697e929e726aeaebf0eba3`

I did the changes that the documentation was asking, but when i try to recreate the signature by the postman, well, It gets wrong.

Comment: How did you create the signature?

Comment: Hello, i created the request by using a python code and adapting to the params my request needs, and I can't use any aws-sdks because of the limitations of my project.
So, i'm trying to replicate the signature and convert it to Microsoft Power Automate.
Python code used:[github](https://github.com/jvictorcorreia/canon_request/blob/main/canonical_request.py)

Comment: But i didnt created the signature, first i'm trying to create the canonical request to calculate the signature.

Comment: but I created the signature of the example used in the documentation with the Code: [AWS Signature github](https://github.com/jvictorcorreia/canon_request/blob/main/aws_signature.py)